# React Native: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native

Unable to resolve "crypto-js" from "node_modules@kinde-oss\react-native-sdk-0-7x\dist\SDK\Utils.js"

```
I am logging in to the app with Kinde.com and I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiZXz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEkCk.png)

I have tried a number of ways to fix it but it didn't work
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.